# How to paste a file from Clipboard to specific path

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How I can Paste from Clipboard a file to my path? I work in VB .NET. I got filename from clipboard but don't know how to extract file from cliboard and save it to my folder.

```
  Dim data As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()
  If data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
     Dim files As String() = data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
  End If
```

Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Path` class to both isolate the file name and create the path of the new file to use in a file copy operation:

```
Dim data As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject
If data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
  For Each s As String In data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
    Dim newFile As String = Path.Combine("c:\mynewpath", Path.GetFileName(s))
    File.Copy(s, newFile)
  Next
End If
```

Example needs error checking.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the full path to the file as follows:

```
Dim objeto As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject
For Each data As String In objeto.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
    ...
    Dim newFile As String = Path.GetFullPath(data.ToString)
    ...
Next
```